# Filling a dataframe with the result of a formula using other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty dataframe returnsDf that I would like to fill in te following way.

I have 2 other dataframes rollReturnRandomDf with an integer index which looks like this:

```
    BBG.KABN.S  BBG.TKA.S   BBG.CON.S   BBG.ISAT.S
index
0   -0.004881   0.008011    0.007047    -0.000307
1   -0.004881   0.008011    0.007047    -0.000307
2   -0.005821   -0.016792   -0.016111   0.001028
3   0.000588    0.019169    -0.000307   -0.001832
4   0.007468    -0.011277   -0.003273   0.004355
```

and dayPricesDf indexed by date, which looks like this:

```
            BBG.KABN.S  BBG.TKA.S   BBG.CON.S   BBG.ISAT.S
date                
23/02/2015  462.078     22.925      3094.817328 12.102837
```

I would like to loop through the rows of rollReturnRandomDf if it is the first row, then I would like to:

```
returnsDf[first_row]  = dayPricesDf *exp(rollReturnRandomDf [first_row])
```

where the dayPricesDf is multiplied by the exponential of the first row of the returnsDf dataframe

For subsequent rows I would like to take the result from the previous row of the returnsDf and multiple this by the corresponding row from the rollReturnRandomDf  dataframe such that the formula would look something like:

```
returnsDf[current row] = returnsDf[current_row -1] * exp(rollReturnRandomDf[current_row]
```

I have tried to code this is the following way:

```
for row in rollReturnRandomDf:

            if dayCount == 0:

               returnsDf[row] =  dayPricesDf[row]*np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf[row])

            else:

                returnsDf[row] =  returnsDf[row-1]*np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf[row])

            dayCount = dayCount + 1
```

So I would end up with a resulting returnsDf dataframe

```
    BBG.KABN.S  BBG.TKA.S   BBG.CON.S   BBG.ISAT.S
index
1   459.8280926 23.10938976 3116.703531 12.099122
2   457.5891403 23.2952626  3138.744511 12.09540814
3   454.9332514 22.90735454 3088.581373 12.10784861
4   455.2008308 23.35070131 3087.633324 12.08568734
5   458.6129958 23.08885464 3077.54402  12.13843528
```

However I get the error message 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'' for the line:

```
returnsDf[row] =  returnsDf[row-1]*np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf[row])
```

Could someone let me know where I have gone wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: The iterable returned from a df are the columns so this line`for row in rollReturnRandomDf:` is wrong, if you want to iterate over the rows then use [`iterrows()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) or just use `for row in rollReturnRandomDf.index`

Answer (score 1):

The iterable returned from a df are the columns so this line is wrong:

```
for row in rollReturnRandomDf:
```

You should either use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) or

```
for row in rollReturnRandomDf.index:
```

Note that what you're doing can be achieved in a vectorised way using:

```
returnsDf = dayPricesDf.shift() *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf)
```

To mask the first row off you can just do:

```
returnsDf.iloc[1:] = dayPricesDf.iloc[1:].shift() *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks.  In the masking formula I need to reference the previous row in the rollReturnRandomDf data frame and not the dayPricesDf dataframe in a formula something like: returnsDf.iloc[1:] = rollReturnRandomDf .iloc[previous_row:].shift() *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[current row:]).  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking about the first row? you just do : `returnsDf.iloc[0] = dayPricesDf.iloc[0] *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[0])` there is no need for `shift`

Comment: Thanks EdChum, How about if I wanted to continue this for additional rows but using the  returnsDf result from the previous row in the current row formula, so the formula would be something like returnDf [current_row] = resultDf[previous_row] * np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf[current_row)

Comment: i have tried                                                                                      returnsDf[2:] = returnsDf.iloc[2:].shift(1) *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[2:])
    print(returnsDf)     but I get the error ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to do here? My code doesn't require a loop as I think its unnecessary

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear.  The first row needs to be treated differently to subsequent rows, (the first row is the seed for other rows).  The first row uses the dayPricesDf in the formula.  For the other rows the instead of using dayPricesDf dataframe I need to use the result from the previous row in the returnsDf dataframe.

Comment: for row 1 I am using  returnsDf = dayPricesDf.iloc[0:1] * np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[0:1]) which works fine.  its the formula for the other rows that I can't get to work.  I tried returnsDf[2:] = returnsDf.iloc[2:].shift(1) * np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[2:]) but I get the error 'ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82597/discussion-between-stacey-and-edchum).

Comment: You don't need to slice for the first row, just `returnsDf = dayPricesDf.iloc[0] * np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[0])` will just work, for the rest of the rows `returnsDf.iloc[1:] = dayPricesDf.iloc[1:].shift() *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[1:])` should work unless your dfs are different lengths

Comment: Thanks, but for the rest of the rows i need to use the returnsDf for the row before and not the dayPricesDf, so instead of using dayPricesDf.iloc[1:].shift()in the formula, how do I look back to the row before in the returnsDf dataframe please?

Comment: Sorry so you just want `returnsDf.iloc[1:] = returnsDf.iloc[1:].shift() *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[1:])`?

Comment: Thanks EdChum, your help is much appreciated.  When I run the line returnsDf.iloc[1:] = returnsDf.iloc[1:].shift() *np.exp(rollReturnRandomDf.iloc[1:]) the code runs but not additional output is produced?

Comment: Is your `returnsDF` initially a blank df? If so then I think you can't avoid looping to populate the df as you can't perform a calculation on the generated df using normal pandas calls